# should std::auto_ptr<>::operator = reset / deallocate its existing pointee?

Tags: c++, stl, visual-c++, smart-pointers, auto-ptr

I read [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/memory/auto_ptr/operator=/) about std::auto_ptr<>::operator=

> Notice however that the left-hand side
>   object is not automatically
>   deallocated when it already points to
>   some object. You can explicitly do
>   this by calling member function reset
>   before assigning it a new value.

However, when I read the source code for header file `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\ce\include\memory`

```
template<class _Other>
    auto_ptr<_Ty>& operator=(auto_ptr<_Other>& _Right) _THROW0()
    { // assign compatible _Right (assume pointer)
    reset(_Right.release());
    return (*this);
    }

auto_ptr<_Ty>& operator=(auto_ptr<_Ty>& _Right) _THROW0()
    { // assign compatible _Right (assume pointer)
    reset(_Right.release());
    return (*this);
    }

auto_ptr<_Ty>& operator=(auto_ptr_ref<_Ty> _Right) _THROW0()
    { // assign compatible _Right._Ref (assume pointer)
    _Ty **_Pptr = (_Ty **)_Right._Ref;
    _Ty *_Ptr = *_Pptr;
    *_Pptr = 0; // release old
    reset(_Ptr); // set new
    return (*this);
    }
```

What is the correct/standard behavior? How do other STL implementations behave? If the website cited above has wrong/outdated information, which website do you recommend as a reference?

Comment: I predict you'll get at least 3 answers warning you not to use auto_ptr. I wish I had the standard at hand, so I could verify your reference.

Comment: I won't put an answer, but I will add this *comment* that you shouldn't use `auto_ptr`. Use `boost::scoped_ptr` or `boost::shared_ptr` instead.

Comment: As an FYI, I submitted an error report at cplusplus.com.  I don't know whether they actively correct content errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the `auto_ptr` being assigned to already holds a pointer, that pointer must be deleted first.

From the 2003 standard (§20.4.5.1):

```
auto_ptr& operator=(auto_ptr& a) throw();
```

> 7 Requires: The expression `delete get()` is well formed.
>
> 8 Effects: `reset(a.release())`.
>
> 9 Returns: `*this`.

So, assigning to an `auto_ptr` has the same effect as calling `reset` on it with the pointer released from the right hand side `auto_ptr`.

The website you cite is wrong.

Comment: Do you have any link(s) for me to click? (link to the standards / other references I can use for daily use)

Comment: You have to purchase the 2003 specification if you want it.  You can get the Final Committee Draft (FCD) of the C++0x standard here:  http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3092.pdf (note that it's not final, official, or normative).

Comment: @afriza: Secret hint: Google for "14882 pdf"